# Ubnt 16.04 - NGINX - LetsEncrypt - 502 Bad Gateway for first time users of website

Tags: php, nginx, letsencrypt

I set up a web server for two Wordpress websites. Installed NGINX, PHP, Mariadb, certbot for SSL, etc.

The problem I´m facing is that if I visited the website earlier than Certbot´s config, I can access it normally, load different pages, admin panel, php works perfectly and everything is displayed and working fine. Nervertheless, if you are a new user that tries to access the website (https://liventplanning.com) you get a 502 - Bad Gateway error.

Here´s NGINX's error.log:

```
2018/07/10 14:47:25 [error] 3425#3425: *1628 upstream sent invalid status "Service Unavailable" while reading response header from upstream, client: 37.9.113.120, server: liventplanning.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "liventplanning.com"
```

And here´s NGINX´s ../sites-available/default file (I removed all comments and most spaces, for simplicity):

```
server {
    server_name liventplanning.com;        
    root /var/www/liventplanning;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                # proxy_http_version 1.1;
                # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                # proxy_set_header Host $host;
                # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

               # With php7.0-cgi alone:
               #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
               # With php7.0-fpm:
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/liventplanning.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/liventplanning.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
       server_name megalaboratorio.com;
       root /var/www/megalaboratorio;
       index index.php index.html;
       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/liventplanning.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/liventplanning.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
        root /var/www/liventplanning;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.megalaboratorio.com www.liventplanning.com; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                # proxy_http_version 1.1;
                # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                # proxy_set_header Host $host;
                # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

               # With php7.0-cgi alone:
               #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
               # With php7.0-fpm:
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/liventplanning.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/liventplanning.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = liventplanning.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name liventplanning.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = megalaboratorio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name megalaboratorio.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.megalaboratorio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.liventplanning.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.megalaboratorio.com www.liventplanning.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Any browser that has previously visited the site can use it perfectly, but if you are a new user, you get a 502 bad gateway.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I´ve been checking documentation, config files, forums and logs for a week and am still baffled by this. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is `php-fpm` running, you're getting the 502 for .php files, i tried with `somefile.gif`and i get a 404, with `index.php` i get a 502. Try restarting php-fpm with `sudo service php-fpm restart`. Possibly the service has the version of php on it, so write until `sudo service php` and press TAB to autocomplete, then add `restart`.

Comment: The strange thing is that php-fpm service is running perfectly.
`[09-Jul-2018 14:34:27] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 2892
[09-Jul-2018 14:34:27] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[09-Jul-2018 14:34:27] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[10-Jul-2018 18:37:15] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[10-Jul-2018 18:37:15] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[10-Jul-2018 18:37:15] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful`

Comment: Also, if I go to websiteURL/wp-admin, it displays perfectly and I can completely interact with the website, change configs and everything. If I go back to index.php it works fine. The thing it´s for the first time I access the website I always get 502 bad gateway, but nginx, php and the db are working fine.

Comment: I see OP's answer is specific to his problem. But, the general answer to an error like `502 bad gateway` from nginx is to check the nginx logs in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` on the server. This will give you something more helpful and specific to your problem. The 502 is a general client-side error that could mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this topic, this is what I found out.

The culprit seems to be half wordpress half a bug in nginx. Reading NGINX´s log I found that an action from Wordpress (wp-cron.php) creates a cron job that checks for Wordpress or plugins updates every time a user loads the website, so while executing the cron job, Wordpress seems to drop the SSL socket before the data comes back and never notifies that if it started, completed or whatever.

That is, according to this Wordpress bug report. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32306

Nevertheless, I disabled SSL, revoked the cert and still have the same 502 Bad Gateway error. After many days, I´ll just rebuild the server and install a LAMP stack instead of a LEMP stack, load the last Wordpress backup that was made, and finally issue a new Let´s Encrypt cert.

Comment: Bad Gateway usually means you didn't configure FPM right.  Depending on which Ubuntu you are using, the socket might not be `php7.0-fpm.sock`